# Exception gathering view hierarchy information -[UITextView _firstBaselineOffsetFromTop] only valid when using auto layout

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview-hierarchy

I'm getting this warning in the console output when i try to debug the view hierarchy in Xcode 9.

> Exception gathering view hierarchy information -[UITextView _firstBaselineOffsetFromTop] only valid when using auto layout`

I'm not sure what it means and I can't see the view hierarchy.

Comment: I have the same issue. I am using auto layout, as far as I can tell it isn't even optional any more